# Datatables combine data from different columns into single row

Tags: sql, database, merge, rows

Refer to the below image, how to merge all chapter into one single rows of different page number?

[image]

e.g.
Page 1 has 3 rows as there are 3 data at columns of chp 8,9,10
Page 2 has 5 rows as there are 5 data at columns of chp 8,9,1,11,12

So
how to have a single row of each page number and the all data placed at their own chp?

Basic SQL as below:

```
SELECT  `mc_ee_page_id` as Page,
 IF ( mc_ee_chp_id = 1,  ( CASE 
 WHEN (is_marked = 0 and mk_no_mark = 1 ) THEN  "Y"  
 WHEN (is_marked = 1 and mk_no_mark = -1) THEN  "N" 
 WHEN (is_marked = 1 and mk_no_mark = 1 ) THEN  "O"  ELSE "X"
 END  ) , "" ) AS chp_1 ,

IF ( mc_ee_chp_id = 2,  ( CASE 
 WHEN (is_marked = 0 and mk_no_mark = 1 ) THEN  "Y"  
 WHEN (is_marked = 1 and mk_no_mark = -1) THEN  "N" 
 WHEN (is_marked = 1 and mk_no_mark = 1 ) THEN  "O"  ELSE "X"
 END  ) , "" ) AS chp_2 ,

IF ( mc_ee_chp_id = 3,  ( CASE 
 WHEN (is_marked = 0 and mk_no_mark = 1 ) THEN  "Y"  
 WHEN (is_marked = 1 and mk_no_mark = -1) THEN  "N" 
 WHEN (is_marked = 1 and mk_no_mark = 1 ) THEN  "O"  ELSE "X"
 END  ) , "" ) AS chp_3 ,
:
:
IF ( mc_ee_chp_id = 12,  ( CASE 
 WHEN (is_marked = 0 and mk_no_mark = 1 ) THEN  "Y"  
 WHEN (is_marked = 1 and mk_no_mark = -1) THEN  "N" 
 WHEN (is_marked = 1 and mk_no_mark = 1 ) THEN  "O"  ELSE "X"
 END  ) , "" ) AS chp_12 

FROM `maxcare_mc_ee_hw` 
WHERE `stud_id` = '3312' AND `mc_ee_level_id` = '1'  

GROUP BY mc_ee_chp_id, mc_ee_page_id
ORDER BY  mc_ee_page_id asc
LIMIT 500
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to `GROUP` the results of your SQL by making it the subquery of an outer query...

```
SELECT Page, MAX(chp_1) AS chp_1, MAX(chp_2) AS chp_2, MAX(chp_3) AS chp_3, MAX(chp_4) AS chp_4, MAX(chp_5) AS chp_5, MAX(chp_6) AS chp_6, MAX(chp_7) AS chp_7, MAX(chp_8) AS chp_8, MAX(chp_9) AS chp_9, MAX(chp_10) AS chp_10, MAX(chp_11) AS chp_11, MAX(chp_12) AS chp_12
FROM
(

-- *** paste your SQL in here ***

) AS indivdual_rows
GROUP BY Page
```

It assumes a page cannot have more than one non-blank value for the same chapter. If that is not the case, then it will only show the `MAX` alphabetical value.

Click [here to go to SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/543713/7) to see it in action.